# How to pass DateTime values to AJAX and then to a controller action?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I have the following in a page:

```
@{
    var fromDate = DateTime.Today;
    var toDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
}

<button type="button" onclick="getData('@fromDate, @toDate')">Get data</button>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function getData(from, to) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Customers")',
                data: {
                    fromDate: from,
                    toDate: to
                },
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#dataId").html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

And the controller:

```
public IActionResult GetData(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    return ViewComponent(nameof(GetCustomerData), new { fromDate, toDate });
}
```

But the parameters are not being passed to the controller. The values are `MinDate`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think this is an issue with data types. The Controller method is expecting a DateTime, but what you're telling the server with your 'contentType' that you're sending JSON.

Comment: if still now working you can give a try by using model with properties datefrom and dateto that often works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the syntax in onclick attribute is wrong. The following code should work:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getData('@fromDate', '@toDate')">Get data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass DateTime values to AJAX and then to a controller action?
> But the parameters are not being passed to the controller. The values
> are MinDate.
>
> What am I missing

According to your description and shared code snippet, I have investigated your code snippet and I think its correct and at my side its working fine.

However, there, might be an issue with how you're passing the DateTime values from the Razor page to the JavaScript function and then to the controller action.

Based on my test and the investigation I am guesing problem may be lies in how you are concatenating the DateTime values in the `onclick` attribute of the button depending on browser. Instead of just using `@fromDate, @toDate`,You can format the DateTime values to be properly handled by JavaScript.

But then again, I found your code still working while I was testing.

Therefore, I have tested in following way and its working as expected:

```
@{
    var fromDate = DateTime.Today;
    var toDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
}

<button type="button" onclick="getData('@fromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")', '@toDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")')">Get data</button>


@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function getData(from, to) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "SoScenarioTest")',
                data: {
                    fromDate: from,
                    toDate: to
                },
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#dataId").html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Your `onclick="getData('@fromDate, @toDate')"` should also work. But if still doesn't work, you can try the way I have provided. Make sure, other script doesn't blocking that or not creating error. You can check browser network trace as well. In addition, you can also [refer to the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1#sending-form-data-via-ajax) for more example and details.

[image]